# How can I resolve the "Table 'dbo.Foo' already exists." error when the table does not exist?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've created a table and then realised I made a mistake. SSMS wouldn't let me update the table without recreating it, so I've deleted the table and then tried to create it again.

It won't let me do this, and I get an error dialog

> Table 'dbo.Foo' already exists.

So I try to delete it again:

```
drop table dbo.Foo
```

> Cannot drop the table 'dbo.Foo', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Refreshing the IntelliSense cache does not help.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Closing and restarting SSMS seems to be the only way to get rid of the error. After doing so, I can again successfully create the table.

Comment: 3 years later, the problem is still here... Why does that bug has't been resolved yet ?

Comment: Its still there in SSMS 2016

Comment: yup. 2017, still here. this is the only working answer. Can't wait to switch to mysql.

Comment: yup 2019. still here.

Comment: This bug still exists in SSMS v18.3

Comment: It's 2020. I just spent a couple wasted hours trying to figure out why I couldn't re-create a table. Thanks for this answer! Now, I'd like to ask M$ what the actual (beep) already, but they seem to have their hands full deploying broken windows 10 updates. Maybe in 5 more years?

Comment: Bl**dy Microsoft. Have made a load of edits in an SSMS diagram because I need to generate a change script. And now I have to restart SSMS and lose all my work because I can't re-use the name of a table I just deleted from memory. Can't save my changes because I need all the changes to be in a single change script. Bah 

Comment: 2022 and it still doesnt work...

Answer (score 23):

Create the Table with any other name and then rename it works fine. Server refresh did not work for me. You can try to restart Management Studios though.

Comment: You just saved me a lot of swearing right at the end of the week :) Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me!  Much better/faster than a full restart of SSMS and loss of your new table specification requiring you to start all over.

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem.  Right-click on your server connection and select 'Refresh'.  I did this and was able to save the recreated table without restarting SSMS.

Answer (score 8):

To change this, on the **Tools** menu, click **Options**, expand **Designers**, and then click **Table and Database Designers**. Select or clear the **Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created** check box.

Comment: I should add that this is not a safe option for production environments or editing databases with pre-existing data. But I won't lie - it solved the problem!

Answer (score 7):

I found that you just need to close all the 'delete's table' TAB from SSMS and it's done

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have no non-saved table changes (better to close all tabulators and try it again)

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the Server, click on Refresh and try again! Worked like a charm for me. Hope the same works for you as well.