# There is already an object named 'Reports' in the database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

When I try a delete migrations and try to start over with a new migration it comes up with the error that object already exists.

```
public enum Priority 
{
    Low,
    Medium,
    High,
    Urgent,
    Compliance
}
public class Report
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfRequest = DateTime.Today;
    public Priority Priority { get; set; }

    public string RequestedBy { get; set; }

}
public class ReportDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought.  No I didn't hit any errors while migrating.

Comment: I realize this is an obvious question, but I do see the dbo.Reports table, but why would it try to recreate it.  Was that from the update-database command?

Comment: Not sure what that is.

Comment: I just saw drop and truncate online.  I'll try it.

Comment: That worked - thanks.  Was the reason it tried to create a 'new' Reports because of the changes in the model?  It seems like that shouldn't have been the case.

Comment: I am not sure what tools you're using, assuming SSMS and SQL server so there is a known bug in the SSMS that seems to be catching or sort of like keeping the transaction of the DROP TABLE in a *recycle bin* until the environment is restarted.

Comment: Oh ok.  Yes I'm using SSMS and SQL Server.  Thanks much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resolve the "Table 'dbo.Foo' already exists." error when the table does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702699/how-can-i-resolve-the-table-dbo-foo-already-exists-error-when-the-table-doe)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete data in table __MigrationsHistory, then re-enable migration, add migration and update database. Looks like there are some migration that you missed.

Comment: I've already dropped the table now, but next time I run into this issue, I'm going to try to do this before getting rid of the data.  I think you are right that there were some migrations I missed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here - https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/13/resetting-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-clean-slate where in this article to save your database, you delete your migrations and start over, then commment out the UP function of your initial migration as it looks to create the database again.